# TASM program hangs up

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

I have the following TASM program
It reads an integer value from address 0x8f77fff4

It won't print a character to screen and hangs up (won't terminate)...why?

even if I activate the jmp char1 instructions it won't terminate and return to C:\ prompt

I corrected the line  add eax,ds:[si] to include the ':'

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100h
.DATA
.CODE
.386P

start:
   cld
   pushf
   push ax
   push bx
   push cx
   push dx
   push ds
   push es
   push si

; jmp char1
   mov cx,08f7h
   mov es,cx

   mov eax,es
   shl eax,15h    ;left shift 21 decimal bits

   mov ax,7000h
   mov ds,ax

   mov ax,0fff4h
   mov si,ax

   add eax,ds:[si]

   mov al,[eax]

   mov ah,9h
   mov bh,0h
   mov bl,0h
   mov cx,0h
   int 10h     ;print character to screen

;char1:

   pop si
   pop es
   pop ds
   pop dx
   pop cx
   pop bx
   pop ax
   popf

   mov ah,4ch
   mov al,0h
   int 21h      ;terminate the program

end start
```

Comment: Why are you trying to read from the seemingly random address `0x8f77fff4` ?

Comment: It's also not clear what you mean by _"hangs up"_. Or what you expected to happen when you uncommented that jump to `char1`, since all your program will do then is terminate itself.

Comment: What happens when you single-step it in a debugger?  How are you building this program into an executable, exactly (what commands?)  And what environment are you running it in?  If just push/pop and exiting doesn't work, sounds like something is broken in your setup, or those directives like `.386P` do something problematic.

Comment: Also, what's the point of setting ES when you never use an `es:[]` addressing mode?  Also, you know you could `mov eax, 08f7fff4h`, right?  But that's not the address you're loading from; you `add eax,ds[si]` first which modifies EAX before you deref it.  (is `ds[si]` even the right syntax?  I thought you needed `ds:[si]`, otherwise it would be looking for `ds` as a symbol name, not a segment reg.  Also, `ds` is the default segment base for SI, and for EAX, so if this is real mode, the linear address used by your `[eax]` addressing mode is `(ds<<4) + eax`)